# How to resolve Error "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

Tags: ipad

I am trying to resize an image on the basis of value selected on picker by user.

To this aim, I currently use following code:

```
- (UIImage *)scaleImage:(UIImage *)image toSize:(CGSize)targetSize {  

    CGRect frame;
    UIImage * newImage;
    newImage = image;

        frame = frontImageView.frame;
        frame.size.width = targetSize.width;
        frame.size.height = targetSize.height;
        frontImageView.frame = frame;



    // the pixels will be painted to this array




    CGImageRef imageRef = [newImage CGImage]; (APP crash at this point)
    CGFloat height = targetSize.height;
    CGFloat Width = targetSize.width;
    CGImageAlphaInfo alphaInfo = CGImageGetAlphaInfo(imageRef);


    pixels = (uint32_t *) malloc(targetSize.width * targetSize.height * sizeof(uint32_t));

    // clear the pixels so any transparency is preserved
    memset(pixels, 0, Width * height * sizeof(uint32_t));

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();


    alphaInfo = kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast;

    CGContextRef bitmap =  CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels, Width, height, 8, Width * sizeof(uint32_t), colorSpace, 
                                                          kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(0, 0, Width, height), imageRef);
    CGImageRef ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);

    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];

    CGContextRelease(bitmap);
    CGImageRelease(ref);
    CGImageRelease(newImage);
    return result;  






}
```

If I resize an image, the first time (by 25 % for instance) there is no crash. But afterwards, a crash occurs with the error "exec_BAD_Access". 
How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Put a break point on the line where it crashes and validate that newImage is not nil. I can see that you are assigning the input image to newImage, are you sure that the image is not nil? You could also try running with NSZombieEnabled to see why you might be messaging a dead object (which it looks like you might be doing).

Comment: check weather your image is an auto released object,if so retain it first before sending any message to it in other methods.